# How can I change the div color to alternate colors?

Tags: html, css

Now this would be a relatively easy to solve problem but I have some issues since I have to not touch the HTML code only work in the CSS style section. I managed to change all the paragraphs on my page to alternate colors but now I have to change only the specific paragraphs in the second-div. I tried with the # method and it didn't work I tried to change the color to that specific div and it worked but I don't know how I can make it work with alternate colors, I  watched many tutorials before I decided to ask here. I know it is a beginner question but I can't find a solution. This is the code:

```css
a:nth-of-type(1),
        a:nth-of-type(2) {
          color: red;
        }
        
        a:nth-of-type(3) {
          color: green;
        }
        p:nth-child(2n+1){color: red;}
        p:nth-child(2n+2){color: blue;}
```

```html
<h1>Main Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com/doodles">Google Doodles</a>
<a href="https://www.link-group.eu/" target="_blank">Goto Link Group</a>
<div id="first-div">
 <h2>Subheading</h2>
 <p>Paragraph 2</p>
 <p>Paragraph 3</p>
 <div id="second-div">
  <h3>Sub subheading</h3>
  <p>Paragraph 4</p>
  <p>Paragraph 5</p>
  <p>Paragraph 6</p>
  <p>Paragraph 7</p>
  <p>Paragraph 8</p>
 </div>
</div>
<p>Paragraph 9</p>
<p>Paragraph 10</p>
```

Comment: `#second-div p:nth-child(2n+1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

```css
a:nth-of-type(1),
        a:nth-of-type(2) {
          color: red;
        }
        
        a:nth-of-type(3) {
          color: green;
        }
        p:nth-child(2n+1){color: red;}
        p:nth-child(2n+2){color: blue;}
        
        p.myP:nth-child(2n+1){color: #776677;}
        p.myP:nth-child(2n+2){color: #f6f55f;}
```

```html
<h1>Main Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com/doodles">Google Doodles</a>
<a href="https://www.link-group.eu/" target="_blank">Goto Link Group</a>
<div id="first-div">
 <h2>Subheading</h2>
 <p>Paragraph 2</p>
 <p>Paragraph 3</p>
 <div id="second-div">
  <h3>Sub subheading</h3>
  <p>Paragraph 4</p>
  <p class="myP">Paragraph 5</p>
  <p class="myP">Paragraph 6</p>
  <p class="myP">Paragraph 7</p>
  <p class="myP">Paragraph 8</p>
 </div>
</div>
<p>Paragraph 9</p>
<p>Paragraph 10</p>
```